# Replace a part of a string with units of a number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to implement a function in Google Spreadsheet using JavaScript. I have:

```
var s1 = "000000000000";  // (12 zeros)
var n1 = 1;
```

I have a third number between 1 and 12. If my number is 6 the result would need to be: 111111000000. If my number is 8 the result would need to be 111111110000.

So far I got stuck here:

```
function REP(b1) {

  var s1 = "000000000000" ;
  var n1 = 1;


  if (b1 >=1 && b1 <= 12) {

    return s1.split("0").join(n1) ;

  }
  else{
    return "no value" ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer a simple approach:

```
function rep(b1) {
    var s1 = "000000000000";
    var s2 = "111111111111";
    if (b1 >=1 && b1 <= 12) {
        return s2.slice(0, b1) + s1.slice(b1);
    } else {
        return "no value";
    }
}

console.log(rep(6)); // 111111000000
console.log(rep(8)); // 111111110000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const replacement = "1"
function replaceZeros(n) {
  var result = "000000000000"
  while (n --> 0) { // it actually mean `n-- > 0`, but it looks cooler that way
    result = result.replace(/0/, replacement)
  }
  return result
}
```

This simply replaces the first `0` in the string `n` times.

See [demo on JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/zadezo/1/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 0):

interesting.  i would try

```
function REP(b1) {
  var ret = ""

  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
      if(i < b1){
         ret += "1";
      }
      else{
         ret += "0";
      }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

hrm... there might be a nicer way though...

EDIT: oh yeah, i think you can do:

```
function REP(b1) {
  if(isNaN(b1) || b1 < 1 || b1 > 12){
      return 'no answer';
  }
  return "1".repeat(b1) + "0".repeat(12-b1);
}
```

Comment: `repeat` has very limited browser integration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Array.join` to repeat characters

see following example...

```js
alert(REP(6));

function REP(b1) {
  var s1 = "000000000000";
  var n1 = 1;

  
  if (b1 >=1 && b1 <= 12) {
    return (Array(b1 + 1).join(n1) + s1).substr(0, 12);
  } else{
    return "no value" ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how performant this is but here's a regex method.

```
function REP(b1) {
  if (b1 < 1 || b1 > 12) return 'no value';
  var rx = new RegExp('0{' + b1 + '}');
  return '000000000000'.replace(rx, Array(b1 + 1).join(1));
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nxbtu8e1/1/)